# Uppercase first letter, naming convention for curryed definitions?

Tags: scala, currying

In Play2 documentation, I find things like this:

```
def LoggingAction(f: Request[AnyContent] => Result): Action[AnyContent] = {
  Action { request =>
    Logger.info("Calling action")
    f(request)
  }
}
```

Is it a convention in Scala to use an uppercase first letter for definitions that can be called with `{ ... }` because of curryfication? Or is it just a Play2's choice?

I'm talking about both LoggingAction and Action.

Comment: I see no currying going on this code. Currying is turning a multi-argument function into a series of partially applied functions. For example (A,B,C) => D into A => B => C => D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as @pedrofurla points out in his comment, currying has nothing to do with what you're seeing here. Second, while `LoggingAction` and `Action` behave similarly from the perspective of an API user, it's important to distinguish between them.

`Action` is capitalized by convention because it is the name of a class and a companion object. This may not be obvious from the context since it appears that `Action` is being called like a function, but what's really going on is more subtle. Since the `Action` companion object defines an `apply` method,

```
Action(arg)
```

is treated as shorthand for

```
Action.apply(arg)
```

That is, what looks like a function invocation is really just an invocation of the `Action` object's `apply` method. In cases like this where a method takes a single function as an argument it's common to use braces:

```
Action apply { request =>
   // ...
}
```

`LoggingAction`, on the other hand, is a *method*. Uppercase method names are *not* conventional and could potentially confuse users of the API. However, it may be appropriate in cases like this one, since it creates consistency throughout the API. Generally, the intent of such usage is to make it clear that the call is *creating* some *thing* (here, a logging action) rather than *doing* something. A rough rule of thumb is that **a capital letter indicates a noun**, while **a lowercase indicates a verb**.

Comment: @pedrofurla No, it wouldn't since `LoggingAction` is a method rather than an object. I'm not sure what prompted this comment, but I guess I need to clarify my answer.